# When f(n) is negative, how does master theorem apply?

Tags: recursion, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

Trying to solve this recursion:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 2500 - sqrt(n)
here a = 4, b=2 but my f(n) = 2500 -sqrt(n) 
n^ logb(a) = n ^ log2 (4) = n ^2
```

but f(n) is constant -sqrt(n)

My questions:

1. Can I assume f(n) = Theta(sqrt n)  or is there some trick I should be knowing?
2. Also, while you are at it, if you could explain if having a constant minus sqrt(n) i.e. is the minus sign have any significance? or it can ignored.

This is driving me crazy! Please help!  Thanks!!

Comment: To be honest, I am using master's theorem for the first time, and its just a problem I am trying to solve this for utilising the master theorem. 

My question persists if f(n) is some constant - sqrt(n) or even if its constant -n; do we consider the constant, and the minus sign or simply ignore the constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) has several prerequisites and case requirements.  Violate any one of those, and the theorem or case does not apply.  As best I can see, this case violates the theorem requirement that f(n) be positive.

In practical terms, this says that once you pass 2500^2 nodes, the inter-process communication overhead is negative: the results are collected and collated before their computation is completed.

I strongly suspect an error in the problem statement.